# Reference previous row in a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, reference, row

I have a very simple problem. I'm am trying to set the value of column X to 0 if column Y[n,] does not equal column Y[n-1,]. My issue is that I do not know how to reference a previous row value in R, and then use that value to set the value of another column.

As an example:

```
Y X
1 5
1 1
2 0
2 2
```

X[3,2] is 0 because Y[3,1] does not equal Y[2,1].

I need to basically find all instance of this in a large data-set and set the corresponding X value to 0.

> `data$X <- 0 if data$Y[n] =! data$Y[n-1]`

Is there a simple solution to this in R? It really feels as though there should be.

Thank you

Comment: If one of the answers addresses your problem please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to the post from @markus, with `dplyr` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(X = (Y == lag(Y, default = first(Y))) * X)

  Y X
1 1 5
2 1 1
3 2 0
4 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
Y <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
X <- c(5, 1, 10, 2)
```

an option would be `diff`

```
X * (c(0, diff(Y)) == 0)
# [1] 5 1 0 2
```

The idea is to check if x[i] - x[i -1] equals zero which gives a logical vector that we multiply by `X`

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` option

```
with(df, X * c(TRUE, !(Y[-1] - Y[-length(Y)])))
#[1] 5 1 0 2
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(X = c(X[1], ((duplicated(Y) * X)[-1])))
#  Y X
#1 1 5
#2 1 1
#3 2 0
#4 2 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Y = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), X = c(5L, 1L, 0L, 2L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```